# SQL Server Spatial Join - Counting Points in Polygons

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two layers in Azure SQL:

- BOUNDARIES - Polygon layer, 4326 SRID, Geometry field called **Shape**
- WORKORDERS - Points layer, 4326 SRID, Geometry called **TheShape**

Both have primary keys are called `OBJECTID`, and both have appropriate spatial indexes built.

I want to have an optimised query that will show me a total count of `WORKORDERS` within each `BOUNDARY` (including the boundary Shape field)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM BOUNDARIES a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         OBJECTID,
         TheShape,
         COUNT(*) as total_count
     FROM 
         WORKORDERS
     GROUP BY 
         OBJECTID) b ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.TheShape) = 1
```

Getting error:

> Column 'WORKORDERS.TheShape' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong, and if this is the optimal approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a group by  all the selected  columns not involved in  aggregation function eg:

```
    SELECT a.*
    FROM BOUNDARIES a
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT
            OBJECTID,
            TheShape,
            COUNT(*) as total_count

        FROM WORKORDERS
        GROUP BY OBJECTID, TheShape
        ) b  on a.Shape.STIntersects(b.TheShape) = 1
```

OR

```
    SELECT a.*
    FROM BOUNDARIES a
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT

            TheShape,
            COUNT(*) as total_count

        FROM WORKORDERS
        GROUP BY TheShape
        ) b  on a.Shape.STIntersects(b.TheShape) = 1
```

anyway do the geometrical limit for aggregation  you could obtain the desired  result  this way

If you need  the count  of WORKORDERS for each BOUNDARIES

```
SELECT a.OBJECTID, count(*)
from  BOUNDARIES a
INNER JOIN WORKORDERS b on a.Shape.STIntersects(b.TheShape) = 1
GROUP BY a.OBJECTID
```

and if you need  boudary shape too

```
select a.OBEJECTID, a.Shape, t.my_count
from  BOUNDARIES a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.OBJECTID, count(*) my_count
    FROM BOUNDARIES a 
    INNER JOIN WORKORDERS b on a.Shape.STIntersects(b.TheShape) = 1
    GROUP BY a.OBJECTID
 ) t on a.OBEJECTID = t.OBEJECTID
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have caught that. Is this the best way to do this join? There’s around 50k points and this will be used to render dynamically by GIS staff.

Comment: if you need  the count for each shape  .. or for each objectID  this is the way  .

Comment: 'The type "geometry" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause.'  I get this on both queries.

Comment: Thanks, yes I managed to get a similar query working.  However, I need to return a result that includes BOUNDARY.Shape, total_count so that it can be visualised on a map dynamically